# Autofac: IEnumerable<IInterface> will always return a list of objects derive from IInterface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I inherited a fairly large codebase that makes heavy use of Autofac. I discover something interesting or even slightly puzzling.

I have a class as such

```
public class ClassA
{  
   public ClassA(IEnumerable<IInterface> allObjects)
   {
   }
}
```

And in my projects, I have a few classes that implement `IInterface`, such as

```
public class AInterface:IInterface {};
public class BInterface:IInterface {};
public class CInterface:IInterface {};
```

What is interesting is that if I let Autofac instantiates `ClassA`, then for the `allObjects` parameter, Autofac will give me `List<IInterface>(){AInterface, BInterface, CInterface}`

***It seems like Autofac is going through all the types in the assemblies loaded in the app domain and automagically instantiates the classes that inherit from `IInterface`.***

Is this a documented behavior? And if yes, *where*? Although this works exactly as I intended, I still want to ensure that it is documented and officially supported, so that I' don't rely on undocumented ( and hence subjected to change) behavior that works well only because of chance.

Comment: No idea for autofac, but other containers behave the same way - you need to look at the docs for "how XXXX discovers/automatically adds  types to the container" and separately "what XXXX returns in case multiple implementations of the interface registered in the container". I'm pretty sure you can't find answer to your question directly.

Comment: No, Autofac will not automatically scan your assemblies; not unless you tell it to. So somewhere during the configuration of Autofac, you are either telling it to [explicitly](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html?highlight=Enumerable#enumeration-ienumerable-b-ilist-b-icollection-b) register those three specific implementations, or you call [RegisterAssemblyTypes](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [Implicit Relationship Types](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)

> For example, when Autofac is injecting a constructor parameter of type `IEnumerable<ITask>` it will not look for a component that supplies `IEnumerable<ITask>`. Instead, the container will find all implementations of `ITask` and inject all of them.